# Data type conversions SQL

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have two data extension (DE1 and DE2) with a boolean field called Subscribe, an email address field called EmailAddress and a text field called Campaign. I want to create a Query with the following functionality:

Imagine an scenario like this:

**DE1:**

> **EmailAddress - Subscribe - Campaign**
>
>    a@example.com - True - C1
>    a@example.com - False - C2
>    b@example.com - False - C1
>    b@example.com - False - C2

What I want to do is, in DE1 for each EmailAddress and for each campaign the information within Subscribe field is FALSE change the status field in DE2 from True to False.

**DE2:**

> **EmailAddress - Status**
>
>   a@example.com - True
>   b@example.com - FALSE

In order to know if all the fields are false, I've created a query like this:

```
SELECT
    ccall."Email Address", 
    'Unsubscribed' as Status,
    ccall.Domain,
    ccall.BounceCount,
    ccall."Subscriber Key",
    ccall.SubscriberType,
    ccall.SubscriberID
FROM ENT.DE1 ccall //This is a Shared Data Extension
JOIN ENT.DE2 ALLS ON //This is a Shared Data Extension
    ccall."Email Address" = ALLS.email
WHERE (ALLS.subscribe AS int)
    SUM (ALLS.subscribe)=0
GROUP BY ALLS.subscribe
```

but the following error appear:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near 'SUM'.

I don't know if maybe the problem is that I've written wrong the conversion from Boolean to Number or maybe there is something else wrong.

Comment: the error message is fairly descriptive. The syntax of your WHERE clause is incorrect and I'm not sure I understand the semantics, either. SQL's expecting some sort of expression or comparison that results in a boolean to take place here, but there isn't one. Are you just wanting to update records in DE2 where DE1.Subscribe = 0 ("false")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a [**HAVING**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql) clause for conditions involving aggregation.

And you can't use double-quotes for column names that contain spaces. Use brackets instead.

Also, you're missing a `cast()` in your `GROUP BY` and your `SUM()`.

```
SELECT
  ccall.[Email Address]
, 'Unsubscribed' as Status
, ccall.Domain
, ccall.BounceCount
, ccall.[Subscriber Key]
, ccall.SubscriberType
, ccall.SubscriberID
FROM ENT.DE1 ccall
INNER JOIN ENT.DE2 ALLS ON (ccall.[Email Address] = ALLS.email)
GROUP BY cast(ALLS.subscribe as int)
HAVING SUM(cast(ALLS.subscribe as int)) = 0
```